# Configure Docker for reading large data in Airflow

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have been trying to learn airflow and I am not very familiar with docker. I have a dataset which is about 300Mb in size. I want to read this file using pandas in airflow environment. But I am unbale to do so. **It always returns code -1**. I am not sure if this is a memory(RAM) issue or a storage issue.

I am running airflow on docker. I have windows os and tried using .wslconfig to provide more memory to docker. Currently my .wslconfig looks like this.

```
[wsl2]
memory=8GB
```

Do I need to add anything else to this file? Or I need to configure docker desktop in another way? Or I need to change the docker-compose.yml file for airflow ?

**Note: I am using the default docker-compose.yml file you can find on the official apache airflow page.**